# Is it OFFICIALLY impossible to receive the price of an in-app billing item at runtime?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I saw two questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536532/in-app-billing-security-and-design-questions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533676/android-in-app-billing-item-price)) about the possibility of receiving the price of an item at runtime. There, the answers were 'no'.

I agree with this kind of answer, but I'm searching for an **official** reply, based on **some documentation or something like this**.

Can someone give me this confirmation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android In-App billing item price](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533676/android-in-app-billing-item-price)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature not supported by Google as of now. May be they have future plans. IOS does provide method to get the price. 
I doubt Google or any firm would document a feature they are not or not planning to provide.They would have documented the service/method if it was available.Can't the absence of any mention to such a service/method in developer site be taken as official confirmation?

Comment: Well, I noticed this absence too... And this is the reason why I ask here, also beacause StackOverflow is mentioned (in offial Android web documentation) as a reference forum for Android Developer...