# How to test in-app billing and getSkuDetails?

Tags: android, android-billing

1) Uploaded .apk with

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

2) Added items to the application's product list. And they are Active.

3) Have test account.

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
```

works fine

but after

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener)
```

or

```
Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, mContext.getPackageName(), type, skusBundle);
```

or like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6241631/1991579)

I see empty list of items in response. `skuDetails.containsKey(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST)` is true

So what should i do to get items information?

Comment: Which in app id you are using currently?

Comment: @user406090 That i created in Google Play admin console.

Comment: means you want to get details of "Already purchased item" ? am i ri8?

Comment: @user406090 nop. I want to get details about items (description + price) to display it in game menu.

Comment: i understood this, wait i have code for this one.

Comment: @GrIsHu tnx, but i don't see in this guide how to take items info. I'm using Google IabHelper too...But...
Requests send fine, but in response i see empty list. So, is there problem in project settings or in console settings? i duno )=

Comment: Have you uploaded your products on server ?

Comment: @GrIsHu what? In Google Play console i created products (in IN-APP PRODUCTS tab) and made them active.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to retrieve my in-app products active and in-active, on unsigned and signed apks, so I don't think this is a restriction in Google's side.

You should check your "type", if it's "subs" then it'll return subscription products rather then regular in-app products.
Also, make sure you passing a string array of all the product-ids you wish to get info about, as such:

```
    ArrayList<String> productIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    productIds.add(your_product_id);
    // ... add more product ids here if needed ...
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", productIds);
    result = mService.getSkuDetails(3, your_package_name, "inapp",
                querySkus);
    // use "subs" instead of "inapp" for subscriptions
```

Comment: What is mService?